# Moving from Mysql to nosql later. Code requirements?

Tags: php, sql, database, nosql

When switching between a RDMS (MySQL) to a Graph or Document database, does it require much application code changes or a complete re-write of code? I am using MySQL but plan to switch over in about 5-6 months to a NoSQL implementation for certain modules so I want to advise my development team on best practices on development to minimize time later when the switch happens and also minimize code changes. Current platform is PHP codeignitor with MySQL.Website is a user content site.

Plan is to use the graph DB for the friends component and document DB for storing mail, profile details and activity streams. Currently we have spent over 2 months on creating the schema in MYSQL which seems like a waste given the switch will happen in few months hence I want to avoid as much code changes as possible later.

For one I may need to remove all the SQL queries from the code for these modules?

Comment: Did you use an ORM? If so, you _might_ be okay. Otherwise you're going have to rewrite most everything to do with the model.

Comment: Nope, no ORM. Even application logic like functions/classes?

Comment: Pretty much anything that directly touches the data will have to be rewritten.  My suggestion would be to abstract the logic a bit from mysql, even if it's something as simple as `function query($query){return mysql_query($query);}` and then use query() instead of mysql_query() in the scripting, and then do that for just about all the basic DB functions.  This way, you can come back later and essentially unplug those functions and plug in a new function set with the same names which pulls data from whatever source and returns the results in the same format as MySQL would.

Comment: Is there a performance impact with using dynamic queries? I would think so because it has to first do a lookup what $query1 is, then lookup the values in the DB then display the output to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OQGraph](http://openquery.com/products/graph-engine), which is a plugabble graph engine for MySQL. Could save you some work.

Comment: Seems interesting although need to research if it scales with large volume.

Comment: It's bundled with MariaDB 5.2, so you can download it for tests. I've seen a MySQL University session about it with some really exciting presentations. It certainly looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data access module in your code.  Changes will be localized to that module. You re-compile ONLY the data access module.

Of course if your code was not compiled to separate dll's to begin with you will have to re-structure and re-compile most of the project.

You must realize this is an interface change, not a mere implementation change. There is no magic best practice in the world that can protect you from interface change. All that you can do is rely on a properly structured code base compiled to separate DLL's to localize code changes and re-compilation.

Comment: PHP is not a compiled language (compiled to executable - it might be, but in general is not) but properly structuring the application is always a good idea ;)

Comment: I am lost. What does this mean in english? :)